# I have created a simple test portfolio site, but the images move on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a simple test website where the user can edit a jQuery code to insert images into a portfolio. I have created the html and css and everything but when i resized the screen the images moved. I would like the screen to just move over top the images. How can i do this, i tried putting position:absolute; but that did not work. All help would be appreciated! THANKS!

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Portfolio</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body> 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
  <div class="imageBlocks">
   <div class="img1">
    <img src="/" alt="Cannot load image">
   </div>
   <p class="label">Brick image</p>
   <a href="#">Read more &gt&gt</a>  
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
body{
 width:80%;
 margin-left:100px;
}
.container{
 width:100%;
}
img{
 height:100px;
 width:200px;
 margin:30px;

}
.imageBlocks{
 height:100px;
 width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:30px;

}
.imageBlocks p{
 font-family:Arial;
 text-align:center;
}
.imageBlocks a{
 font-family:Arial;
 margin-left:50px;
 color:#3CABCE;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
//Bellow you can change the images and add new ones!
//<---If you would like to change it, just change the location                             
//The number beside the .img is the the image that will change, from right to left
//  |Image #|               |Location|
$(".img1 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img2 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img3 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img4 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img5 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img6 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img7 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img8 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img9 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img10 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
$(".img11 img").attr("src", "brick.png");
});
```

And you can use just any image at all because it resize with css

Also as you can see, I used javascript/jquery to change the images, but is there an easier way i could learn? Maybe some type of config file? I only ask because someone has asked me to make a website like this where they can easily change the images without a database.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a fixed width to the container div.  The current 100% width will make it cover 100% of the window when resized - so the images will stack on minimizing.  If you set the width in pixels it should stay.  You can also do an xml file for client if you know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Set container `min-width` to your liking, or if you would like it to always remain the same size set `width` to that value.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly41gog5/